# How to split a time duration row by one hour period in Mysql

Tags: mysql, datetime, intervals

I have start time. From there, I used lead function to get the end time and calculate the duration. Now I am trying to split a time duration row by hour. This is the current code and output:

```
SELECT `time`, LEAD(time,1,null) OVER (ORDER BY time asc) time_end, 
unix_timestamp(LEAD(time,1,null) OVER ( ORDER BY time asc)) - unix_timestamp(time) as 
duration
FROM test_table
```

Current Output:

```
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
| name |        start        |         end         | (duration)s   |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
|  me  | 2017-04-03 23:00:00 | 2017-04-03 23:30:00 |          1800 |
|  me  | 2017-04-03 23:30:00 | 2017-04-04 00:45:00 |          5100 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 10:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:00:00 |          3600 |
|  me  | 2017-04-04 11:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:30:00 |          1800 |
+------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Expected Output:

```
 +------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
 | name |        start        |         end         | (duration)s   |
 +------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
 |  me  | 2017-04-03 23:00:00 | 2017-04-03 23:30:00 |          1800 |
 |  me  | 2017-04-03 23:30:00 | 2017-04-04 00:00:00 |          1800 |
 |  me  | 2017-04-03 00:00:00 | 2017-04-04 00:45:00 |          2700 |
 |  me  | 2017-04-04 10:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:00:00 |          3600 |
 |  me  | 2017-04-04 11:00:00 | 2017-04-04 11:30:00 |          1800 |
 +------+---------------------+---------------------+---------------+
```

Comment: note that unix_timestamp treats the times as being in the session timezone; are they really?

Comment: yes the reason i used unix_timestamp is to get the duration in seconds

Comment: I understand that, but what timezone is test_table.time in?  It's not a good idea to treat it differently just based on how you are connected.  (and the splitting into hours definitely needs to work differently depending on if these times are utc or are in some timezone with dst)

Comment: its based on utc +8:00

Comment: but i have converted the timezone before doing this query in javascript

Comment: utc +8 with no daylight savings?  that doesn't sound right; I think the Pitcairn Islands use that but it isn't at all a common thing

Comment: not sure what you mean by "converted the timezone before doing this query"? you are reading what is stored in the table, my question was about that

Comment: yes i am reading the data from the table